# How to avoid full load content at first time from firestore in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I want to listen to the content only if there are any changes in the collection. But when I tried `StreamSubscription`, all contents are loaded for the first time.

How can avoid full load for the first time?

```
 static StreamSubscription<dynamic> listenMessageChange(Function contentChange) {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('contents')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) {
          List<Message> changedContents = [];
          data.documentChanges.forEach((change) {
            changedContents.add(Content.createFromMap(change.document.data));
          });
          contentChange(changedContents);
    }, cancelOnError: false);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When listening for realtime updates, at first time all the data will be retrieved. The only way to avoid full load content is to use the method `limit()` so you dont get everything at first load. After that you can check which document changed/added/removed:

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection('contents')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) {
      data.documentChanges.forEach((res) {
      if (res.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
        print("added");
        print(res.document.data);
      } else if (res.type == DocumentChangeType.modified) {
        print("modified");
        print(res.document.data);
      } else if (res.type == DocumentChangeType.removed) {
        print("removed");
        print(res.document.data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: If there is a change in old content, I don't get a callback here, after use `limit`. I need to get a callback only when there is a change in any of the content.

Comment: Thats because when using limit it will always return the same number of documents. But the only way to limit the content loaded is to either use `limit` or try to use pagination https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors other than that you have to change the structure to retrieve less documents then on every change the callback will be called